# calculating e^1 using C

Tags: c, series

i am trying to calculate e^1 using C programming(with input of tolerance level) this works but for some reason i get the wrong output like this:

The exp to 0.000100 error tolerance: 2.000000

The exp to 0.000000 error tolerance: 2.000000

The exp to 0.000000 error tolerance: 2.000000

The exp to 0.000000 error tolerance: 2.000000

Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//this function creates factorial of n 
int myfac(n)
{
if (n <= 1) return 1;
return n*myfac(n - 1);
}
void myexp(float error)
{
int n = 0;
float value = 0;
//n, n being used for recursion
//error, user input error for tolerance
//value, exp being returned as an answer
//nextvalue, value at n+1
while(1/myfac(n) >= error)
{
    value = value + 1 / myfac(n);
    n = n + 1;
}
printf("The exp to %f error tolerance: %f \n", error, value);
}
void main()
{
    myexp(0.0001);
    myexp(0.0000001);
    myexp(0.0000000001);
    myexp(0.0000000000001);


}
```

Comment: your way of counting factorial is very inefficient because you're calculating `myfac(i)` again and again for every `myfac(j)` with `j >= i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `1/myfac(n)`, both sides of the fraction are integers. If `n` is greater than 1, the result will round down to zero.

Try `1./myfac(n)` instead, with a decimal point indicating the `double` numeric type.